# Need a 48v relay but I don't know the terminology

Tags: relay, terminology

I need a little terminology help so I can search for and obtain the correct relay.

The relay will control a 48v 32a circuit.  It should be normally open unless a signal is present.  If the signal is present, the relay will close to complete the 48v circuit .  The signal current level is 175mA maximum.

The relay will not be on a PCB or rack of any kind, but probably mounted on a plywood board.

Does such a relay exist? How would it be described? Someone said I'd need to amplify the small signal in order to control large contactors.  Is that true, and if so, how would I configure (or describe) that?

If someone has a specific brand or part to recommend, that would certainly be welcome.

EDIT: I have a 48v battery bank of LiFePO4 cells.  The SOC cannot drop below a certain percentage or it will damage the cells.  The battery management system (BMS) has a method to send a signal if the pack is okay to use.  Here is what the BMS manual says:

*An open drain digital on/off signal (is) used to signal to a load that the load can discharge the battery.  This would normally be used to control a discharge contactor or to signal to a controller that discharge must be stopped if this signal is not present.  This signal can be used as a backup to digital CAN communication with a controller.  This is a signal current level (175mA max) and should be amplified for controlling large contactors or relays.*

So it would seem that I need a relay, but there are so many types I'm having difficulty knowing how to narrow the search to what I need.

Answer (score 4):

> The relay will control a 48v 32a circuit.

Your relay will require a coil voltage to suit your control circuit voltage. You haven't stated this as other than "signal".

The contact(s) will require a rating of ≥ 48 V DC and ≥ 32 A DC. (note capital 'V' for volt and 'A' for ampere.)

> It should be normally open unless a signal is present.

Almost all relays feature a normally open (NO) contact. One with a changeover contact can be used. The normally closed (NC) contact would be left unterminated.

> The relay will not be on a PCB or rack of any kind, but probably mounted on a plywood board.

You are looking for a panel-mount relay base.

> Does such a relay exist? How would it be described?

Yes. Described as 48V DC plug-in relay with 32A DC NO contact.

> Someone said I'd need to amplify the small signal in order to control large contactors. Is that true, and if so, how would I configure (or describe) that?

Please edit your question to supply details of the "small signal".

> If someone has a specific brand or part to recommend, that would certainly be welcome.

Part recommendations and where to buy them are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I edited the question to add info.

Answer (score 0):

You need a relay that's rated for 48VDC or more, and 32A or more, with form A (normally open) or form C (transfer -- this is the sort that @transistor talked about).  Note that relay currents get complicated -- AC current ratings are usually higher, and for DC, "making" or "holding" current is higher than "breaking" current.

If you're going to break a 32A circuit then there's a possibility of some serious inductive kickback, which would need a snubber circuit designed to match the load presented when the relay breaks.  Just a bare relay could undergo some pretty serious arcing every time it opened.

Comment: Any particular kind?  Like above, is there a specific description for this snubber?  When I search on snubbers, I get all kinds of results.

Comment: The problem is that the snubber needs to match the load, and it's getting well into safety-related territory.  If you can find a contactor that's rated for 48VDC, 32A **breaking current** I think that'll be enough (and don't blame me if you burn your house down).